# Table row and column highlighting with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

The [Script](http://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/) is here for highlighting table row and column with jquery.  [Demo Here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/RowColumnHighlighting/example-two.php)

It highlights entire row and entire column on hover.  I want hover only upto current cell and not to extend beyond the current cell row and column position.

Script

```
$("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
  $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
  $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");
}
else {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
  $("colgroup").eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");
}
});
```

Any help ?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eMEq6/2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this code:

**HTML**:

```
<table>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

**JS**:

```
$('td').on('mouseover mouseout', function(){
             $(this).prevAll().addBack()
             .add($(this).parent().prevAll()
             .children(':nth-child(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')'))
             .toggleClass('hover');
      });
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/aEwE4/1/)

Comment: @KingKing How do I apply this if the table is loaded dynamically after the document load? If I put this inside $(document).load(); it doesn't work?

Comment: @GintasK of course the code should be called again after your table is loaded. e.g: If your table is added (set to some innerHTML or child of some existing container) by AJAX query, right after that setting, you can place the code there, it should be refactored into some function for easily reusing. BTW, it's a long time I've not been  involved with website development, so I'm back to a fairly starting point now.

Comment: @KingKing Thanks, will try this :) I am building my table from ajax request data, so I will try to place this event handler after the request.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .parent() and the $("colgroup") sections from your JavaScript.

See the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/eMEq6/6/

Note that you most likely could do the same by just using CSS with the hover attribute.

```
$("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
      $(this).addClass("hover");
    }
    else {  
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
    }
});
```

Also, please note that you can do the same thing with only CSS (though early versions of browsers may not fully support it): http://jsfiddle.net/eMEq6/7/

```
td:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you want something like this:[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KRBVT/)

For what you are trying to achieve you cannot give full rows/cols background colors. You need to add classes to cells individually.

And for that you first need to find the row and column index you are hovering on and highlight all `td`s until that index on all previous rows:

```
$("table").delegate('td','mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
    var cellindex = 0;
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
```

I am adding a class to the current hovered cell to know when to stop.

```
        $(this).addClass("cell");
```

And iterating over all cells of the current row until i find that class.

```
        var cells = $(this).parent().children("td");
        for(var i=0;i<cells.length;i++){
            if($(cells[i]).hasClass("cell")){
                $(this).removeClass("cell");
                cellindex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
```

So the `cellindex` gives me the current column, which we want to highlight up to.

Then i do the same for the row, i am adding a class to current hovered row to know when to stop.

```
        $(this).parent().addClass("row");
        var rows = $(this).parent().parent().children("tr");
```

And add hover class to all cells until the `cellindex` i previously found.

```
        for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
            var tds = $(rows[i]).children("td");
            for(var j=0;j<=cellindex;j++){
                $(tds[j]).addClass("hover");
            }
            if($(rows[i]).hasClass("row")){
                $(this).parent().removeClass("row");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Although you can keep that `cell` and `row` classes and do the reverse here,  i am simply removing all hover classes from all tds.

```
    else {
        $("td").removeClass("hover");
    }
});
```

---

EDIT: re-read the question, this might also be what you want, it's the same with slight changes: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KRBVT/1/)